# ReactJS. How to prevent calling render() before Fetch API working in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using Fetch API in componentWillReceiveProps, but i have some problems with asynchronous. I need to prevent re-render before I will get response from my Fetch request. Now everything is working but I render works 3 times.

Comment: can you please show some code on how you have it set up and why you are fetching in componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: Thanks, I am using redux, and I need call several dispatchs in componentWillReceiveProps. On of distatches call fetching data from server.

Comment: so you're doing multiple dispatches which updates the state after each one and you want to wait until the last one completes before updating state and causing a re-render? You could use shouldComponentUpdate or maybe just create a new action to do all the requests then update the state just once

Comment: @MattAft yes, you understood me right. I used shouldComponentUpdate  but I thought that it's not right way, because I will put lot's of conditions for another parts of my component.

Comment: yeah that's why it might be easier to create an action that does all 3 API requests probably using Promise.all then update state just once

Comment: @MattAft but fetch works async way, so anyway render function running during fetch is working

Answer (score 3):

Maintain a `state` variable for that, initially value of that variable will be `false`, once you get the response properly, change that variable to `true`. Use this variable to `render` the component.

Inside render:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.dataFetched){
        return (/*return component*/)
    }else{
       return <div>Loading....</div>
    }

}
```

One more thing, instead of making network call in `componentWillReceiveProps` method, do that in `componentDidMount` `lifecycle` mthod.

**[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.

Comment: whosever is down voting the answer, please explain the reason also.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable way to handle temporary loading state, dunno why you got downvoted. I've done this heaps of times myself. Also agree with using `componentDidMount` to issue requests. Not sure why but I see so many questions where they try using `componentWillReceiveProps` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not solution for me. componentDidMount works once

Comment: let me know where u r facing the issue, will help you, whats the problem in this solution ? you didn't mention that u need to make many req, so i assumed u r fetching data once.

Comment: @MayankShukla , thanks for responce. I am using redux, react-router, react-router-redux  and I need call several dispatch in componentWillReceiveProps after i call browserHistory.push. So I need re-render my component when componentWillReceiveProps is completed but fetch working asynchronous so render method works 3 times. I hope you understood me. thank you

Comment: time when you are making a network call, what u want to show at that time `loading....` or other content ?